# hibernate-orm-panache-resteasy: {"error":"id to load is required for loading","code":500} running a native build

Tags: java, quarkus

After i tried to test quarkus with a small rest service using hibernate ORM with panache, i get an error just after build a native executable and run it in a docker container. The Point is, it works in dev mode perfectly but not after building native.

The code i am using is copied from the fruit example and changed to person. I use a postgres db in a docker container. The db get initialized with some data through import.sql 
If i run it in dev mode i can make a request on http://localhost:8080/person and get the list of all persons an if i make a request for example on http://localhost:8080/person/2/ i get the person with id 2.
After a native build, i run the service in a docker container. with the same request, i get the list of all persons but if i want to get the person with for example id 2, i get a response code 500 with the error:
{"error":"id to load is required for loading","code":500}
the person with the id 2 exists in the db.

```java
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.jaxrs.PathParam;

import io.quarkus.panache.common.Sort;

/**
 * PersonResource
 */
@Path("person")
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class PersonResource {

    @GET
    public List<Person> get() {
        return Person.listAll(Sort.by("lastName"));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Person getSingle(@PathParam Long id) {
        Person entity = Person.findById(id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Person with id of " + id + " does not exist.", 404);
        }
        return entity;
    }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    public Response create(Person person) {
        if (person.id != null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Id was invalidly set on request.", 422);
        }
        person.persist();
        return Response.ok(person).status(201).build();
    }

    @PUT
    @Path("{id}")
    @Transactional
    public Person update(@PathParam Long id, Person person) {
        if (person.firstName == null || person.lastName == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("First Name or Last Name was not set on request.", 422);
        }

        Person entity = Person.findById(id);

        if (entity == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Person with id of " + id + " does not exist.", 404);
        }

        entity.firstName = person.firstName;
        entity.lastName = person.lastName;

        return entity;
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    @Transactional
    public Response delete(@PathParam Long id) {
        Person entity = Person.findById(id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Person with id of " + id + " does not exist.", 404);
        }
        entity.delete();
        return Response.status(204).build();
    }


    @Provider
    public static class ErrorMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

        @Override
        public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
            int code = 500;
            if (exception instanceof WebApplicationException) {
                code = ((WebApplicationException) exception).getResponse().getStatus();
            }
            return Response.status(code)
                    .entity(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("error", exception.getMessage()).add("code", code).build())
                    .build();
        }

    }

}
```

Here the requests and responses:

```
$ curl -v -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/person'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'localhost,127.0.0.1,*sulzer.de'
*   Trying ::1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /person HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 154
< Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 09:15:14 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[{"id":2,"firstName":"Muster","lastName":"Maxmann"},{"id":1,"firstName":"Max","lastName":"Mustermann"},{"id":3,"firstName":"Mann","lastName":"Mustermax"}]


$ curl -v -X GET 'http://localhost:8080/person/2'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Uses proxy env variable no_proxy == 'localhost,127.0.0.1,*sulzer.de'
*   Trying ::1:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /person/2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.3
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 57
< Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2019 09:15:24 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"error":"id to load is required for loading","code":500}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using `javax.ws.rs.PathParam` instead of `org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.jaxrs.PathParam`?

The `org.jboss.resteasy.annotations.jaxrs.PathParam` is not taken into account so you end up passing `null` to your method and Hibernate ORM with Panache is complaining about the id not being provided when you try to load the entity.

I'll see if we could improve the usability here as I had the very same issue recently.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. It works with the change to  javax.ws.rs.PathParam. Could you please explain me, what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [RESTEasy docs](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.2.0.Final/userguide/html/_NewParam.html) you need to make your compiler generate parameter names if you're using the new annotations. Add this to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    </properties>
```